# Cross value multiplying

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

for the pas few hours I have been working on a excel sheet. But I'm currently stuck with a problem. I'm not so skilled with excel and I cant seem to get this one working.

**My problem**: the value in the red box is supposed to be total sum of all the values in the green box times the corresponding value in the blue box.

So for example:  the first row I enter a grade of 8.3, I would like to get that value multiplied by 10 and added to the total in the last red box. So the total would be 83.

If something is not clear I will try to add some more information.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: Example of my sheet]

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` and `SUBTOTAL` will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "Waardering in %" is in `Column B` and "Raspberry pi 2" is in `Column C`, you can do the following:

Enter `=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B10,C1:C10)` in the RED cell.  Update the formula's ranges as necessary (you can include header rows in your ranges).

More information on [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).

Comment: Thank you, why did I not know of SUMPRODUCT. Great answer!